# Line graph in R comparing values in 2 columns

Tags: r, linegraph

I have two columns in a data frame

```
>head(obs_v_exp)
    observed expected
    1          3.5
    6          8.9
```

How do I plot a line graph in R that shows both observed vs expected as 2 lines in one graph?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
plot(obs_v_exp$observed, type="l")
lines(obs_v_exp$expected, col="red")
```

Here's an example:

```
set.seed(2)
obs_v_exp <- data.frame(observed=sample(0:6, 10, TRUE),
                        expected=sample(0:6, 10, TRUE))
plot(obs_v_exp$observed, type="l")
lines(obs_v_exp$expected, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: type parameter is obsolete, this did not work. thank you though

Comment: Didnt it work? type parameter is obsolete? I dont understand what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `matplot` function:

```
matplot(obs_v_exp, type='l')
```